# Cursor position in textarea with different font and height-line size

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I try to set the font size (13px) and line-height size (23px) for textarea control.

For example the first code: ( http://jsfiddle.net/D6T4f/ )

```
<TEXTAREA style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 23px; height: 70px;"></TEXTAREA>
```

If I click inside the blank textarea the cursor will be located on correct position.

But in this code I include style **background-color**: ( http://jsfiddle.net/4e2dL/ )

```
<TEXTAREA style="background-color: white; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 23px; height: 70px;"></TEXTAREA>
```

I added only one style **background-color: white;**. So, if I try to click inside the textarea the cursor will be located not like in the first code (slightly higher). But If I start typing some text, the cursor will move to correct position.

How to avoid this if I need to use this style?

The problem appears in IE 9. Chrome (latest) is OK.

The same problem caused also if I use style **background-image: none;**

Thanks!

Comment: You should provide the IE version that you are using. Also, setting up a jsfiddle of it would help you get answers more quickly.

Comment: Accept any answer that helped you. Or else post your solution so others can get help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with it only being an IE9 issue, it looks to be a that when you add the background style it is also overriding and removing some other standard IE9 styles.

The solution, you are going to need to be more explicit with your styles to help normalise the styles that are affecting the textareas, I have put an example together where the styles of the textarea have been completely overwritten by the css styles to bring the two inline: http://jsfiddle.net/PXgxU/2/

Comment: Doesn't help in Chrome. What's interesting there's no problem with that in Firefox...

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to remove space or new line between HERE

It might cause because of this.